# WP8.1 AppBarButton holding event

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

How do I detect if AppBarButton is being held? 
There is a Holding event, but it never fires, even if I set AppBarButton's property IsHoldingEnabled to true. Or even when I set CommandBar's IsHoldingEnabled to true.

Comment: how are you checking whether it's fired or not? Using breakpoints?

Comment: I tried a breakpoint in debugging mode, as well as showing a popup from inside of Holding event handler. None works.

Comment: According to the AppBarButton class it should work. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton
Could you post some of your code please?

Comment: It's really simple. XAML: http://pastebin.com/EfppbgJb C#: http://pastebin.com/e4tr9Qjx

Answer (score 0):

Try this code within your `xaml` code for your `appbar`.

```
<page.BottomAppBar>
<commandBar>
    <commandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <appBarButton Label="formatting" 
                      IsHoldingEnabled="True"
                      Holding="AppBarButton_Holding">
            <appBarButton.Icon>
                <pathIcon HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="Some path"/>
            </appBarButton.Icon>
        </appBarButton>
    </commandBar.PrimaryCommands>

</commandBar>
</page.BottomAppBar>
```

[Reference](http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/09/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-application-bar/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sadly, it still doesn't work.
BTW, this code is incorrect. It should say "AppBarButton", "CommandBar" and so on.